# Where can I download JRE 7u5 plugin for any browser?

Tags: security, plugins, java, exploit, metasploit

I was looking for a good exploit to use as my final project for security class so I though for JRE 7u5 bug to exploit using Metasploit.

Where I can download that version of plugin for FireFox/IE/Chrome, for whatever browser?

I Googled for hours now and I can't find a link =?

Answer (score 1):

While the older downloads are not listed any more, I think you'll find that they follow a well-defined naming pattern. For example, look at the download links on this page and modify as needed:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7u9-downloads-1859586.html

Not sure about Chrome, but I believe installing JRE on Windows adds it as browser plug-in for IE and Firefox. If not, follow [these instructions](http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml).

Comment: Well, the link you posted it takes me to different version but this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) takes me where I need to go. :)